# How to automatically create indices in nodes in elasticsearch if not available (when database is empty)

Tags: elasticsearch, spring-data-elasticsearch

Here is a sample code of what I am doing right now:

```
SearchQuery searchQuery = new NativeSearchQueryBuilder().withQuery(query)
                .withIndices(organization+"-"+index_name)                   .addAggregation(AggregationBuilders.terms("Dept").field(QueryConstants.INTERNAL_DEPT).size(size)
                        .showTermDocCountError(true))
                .build();
        return elasticsearchTemplate.query(searchQuery, new ResultsExtractor<JsonNode>() {

            @Override
            public JsonNode extract(SearchResponse response) {
                Terms t = response.getAggregations().get("Dept");
                ArrayNode arrayNode = JsonNodeFactory.instance.arrayNode();
                ObjectNode objectNode = null;
                for (Terms.Bucket b : t.getBuckets()) {
                    objectNode = JsonNodeFactory.instance.objectNode();
                    objectNode.put("department", b.getKey());
                    objectNode.put("hits", b.getDocCount());
                    arrayNode.add(objectNode);
                }
                return arrayNode;
            }
        })
```

The problem is when I run this I get exception when there is no data

```
org.elasticsearch.client.transport.NoNodeAvailableException: None of the configured nodes are available: []
```

**edit**

This is how I setup elastic client:

```
@Bean
public Client client() {
    Settings settings = ImmutableSettings.settingsBuilder().put("cluster.name", esClusterName).build();
    Client client = new TransportClient(settings)
            .addTransportAddress(new InetSocketTransportAddress("localhost", 9300));
    return client;
}
```

I wanted to ask that is there any way to create missing indices on runtime?

Comment: please add how you have set up your elasticsearch client.

Comment: question edited.

Comment: What is the value of `esClusterName` ?

Comment: it is picking value from application.properties file.